# Algolia Places and Rails: Autocomplete Form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, algolia

I have an address form, which I would like to autocomplete upon user typing in the address (in my case starting with the street, which is not an issue, as I tested). Here is what I did so far:

1. Installed gems: algoliasearch-rails and algolia-places-rails
2. Created an autocomplete file: app/assets/javascripts/autocomplete.js and wrote code as described [here](https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#complete-form)

->

```
import places from 'places.js';

(function() {
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'xxx',
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    container: document.querySelector('#form-address'),
    templates: {
      value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
      }
    }
  }).configure({
    type: 'address'
  });
  placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.querySelector('#form-city').value = e.suggestion.city || '';
    document.querySelector('#form-zip').value = e.suggestion.postcode || '';
  });
})();
```

I did install the node_modules: places.js with npm

3.Went back to my view file (which is a part of the multistep form) and added the necessary ids to the form fields app/views/user_steps/address.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="notification">Please finalise your personal information.</p>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal" >

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">     
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dismiss-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>    

        </div>
    <div class="center-items-register-second">

    <%= form_for(@user, url: wizard_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages" %>


        <div class="row second 1">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="field wizard">
                <%= f.label :street, class: 'required' %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :street, id: 'form-address', class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field housenumber">
                    <%= f.label :house_number, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :house_number, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row second 2">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard">
                    <%= f.label :city, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :city, id: 'form-city', class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard zipcode">
                    <%= f.label :zip_code, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :zip_code, id: 'form-zip', class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


            <div class="row btns second 3">
                <div class="column btns">

                     <%= f.submit "Register", class: 'btn form margin second'%>

                </div>
                <% end %>
                <div class="column btns">
                    <%= link_to "Quit", @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Your data won't be saved! Are you sure you want to quit registration process?", title: " " },  class: 'btn form margin second' %>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I also added to my aplication.js file:

```
//= require algolia-places-rails/places.min
```

And I do have a config file for AlgoliaSearch: algoliasearch.rb

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: 'xxx', api_key: 'xxx' }
```

In my form, however, nothing changed. I wish it to be like [this](https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#complete-form).

Answer (score 0):

It took me around 8 hours to find out the problem. First I needed webpacker to manage my packs. So added to my rails app and then installed it

```
# Gemfile
gem 'webpacker'

#Install
bundle install 
rails webpacker:install
```

This creates a new app/javascript/packs -folder, where also a (new) application.js file can be found. There later I would import my function.

But first I needed to go the my address.html.erb and get the actual id, which was hidden and I had to inspect element in the browser. So this code bit should be as follows:

```
<div class="row second 1">
            <div class="column">
              <div class="field wizard">
                <%= f.label :street, class: 'required' %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field housenumber">
                    <%= f.label :house_number, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :house_number, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row second 2">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard">
                    <%= f.label :city, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="field wizard zipcode">
                    <%= f.label :zip_code, class: 'required' %><br />
                    <%= f.text_field :zip_code, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

So no definition of id's in the form. I deleted them.

Next step create a file app/javascript/packs/autocomplete.js

```
import places from 'places.js';

const initAutocomplete = () => {
  var placesAutocomplete = places({
    container: document.getElementById('user_street'),
    templates: {
      value: function(suggestion) {
        return suggestion.name;
      }
    }
  }).configure({
    type: 'address'
  });

  placesAutocomplete.on('change', function resultSelected(e) {
    document.getElementById('user_city').value = e.suggestion.city || '';
    document.getElementById('user_zip_code').value = e.suggestion.postcode || '';
  });
};

export { initAutocomplete };
```

Now actually the places.js can be imported from my node_modules (which I installed before, following the instruction on algolia website.).

Last but not least, as I mentioned above, I went back to app/javascript/packs/application.js and imported my function:

```
import { initAutocomplete } from './autocomplete';
initAutocomplete();
```

So now this works for me just fine! The address paerts are also inserted in the right fields of my form.