# You are loading Turbolinks from a <script> element inside the <body> element - leads to duplicated elements in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a very weird problem. I added an autocomplete option to my form in my Rails App yesterday (Algolia Places). I also installed webpacker, to work with packages inside my App. So, it comes out, that in my address.html.erb I now get two forms displayed under each other: one with autocomplete and other without. See the image below (the first form has autocomplete address and the one underneath doesn't).

[image]

I assume the problem is in my application.html.erb, where the code for now looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neigbornow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <meta>

      <%= yield %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
      <%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
    </meta>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <% if @user.nil? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% elsif user_signed_in? && current_page?(user_step_path) || %>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/header_address" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header_rest' %>
    <% end %>
      <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Console throws following error:

```
You are loading Turbolinks from a <script> element inside the <body> element. This is probably not what you meant to do!

Load your application’s JavaScript bundle inside the <head> element instead. <script> elements in <body> are evaluated with each page change.

For more information, see: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements

——
Suppress this warning by adding a `data-turbolinks-suppress-warning` attribute to: <script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1"></script>
```

If I change

```
<%= yield %>
```

to

```
<%= yield :js %>
```

The second form  disappears, but also the autocomplete function diasppears too. Same happens, if I move

```
<%= yield %>
```

to the end. It's quite a mystery for me. I really need help on this, as there are no matirials for this on the internet.

P.S.
Here is layouts/header

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#">
        <img src="<%= image_path('logo_transparent.png') %>" width="147" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-left mr-2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path, method: :get %></li>
          <li><a>About</a></li>
          <li><a>Search</a></li>
          <li><a>Contact</a>

          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.profile == nil %>
              <li><span class="bg-primary text-white rounded"><%= link_to 'Create profile', new_user_profile_path(current_user.id) %></span></li>
            <% else %>
              <li><span class="bg-primary text-white rounded"><%= link_to 'My profile', user_profile_path(@user) %></span></li>
            <% end %>

          <li><span class="bg-primary text-white rounded"><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></span></li>

        <% else %>
          <li><div class="log-in-btn"><button class="btn" type="submit"><%= link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path %></button></div></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>

    </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

But I am actually rendering another header on this page - an empty one, as you can see

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#">
        <img src="<%= image_path('logo_transparent.png') %>" width="147" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-left mr-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On the firsts page, without the autofill function, this problem doens't appear.

P.S. - edited version

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neigbornow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :meta %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <%= yield :css %>

  </head>
  <body>
    <% if @user.nil? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% elsif user_signed_in? && current_page?(user_step_path) || %>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/header_address" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header_rest' %>
    <% end %>
      <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <!- I would really recommend that you wrap this in an element -!>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off using a meta tag like that is completely invalid. The [meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) is an empty element and thus NEVER has a closing tag or contents.

These are valid examples of meta tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Second you have two "unnamed yields" in your layout. Your layout should only contain a single unnamed yield as that where the template being rendered is actually injected. In this case the content is injected twice and you get a totally mangled document and your error as the browser goes into total slop mode.

The reason turbolinks is warning you that "You are loading Turbolinks from a script element inside the body element." is the aforementioned slop mode. You're injecting a bunch of elements that are not allowed in the `<head>` tag and the browser tries to make sense of the garbage HTML by adding a `<body>` tag.

Your solution of removing the second yield is actually totally bonkers. Its not what you want at all.  Your view should not be rendered inside the `<head>` element of the page. Thats completely invalid HTML and will result in a totally malformed document that will behave really unpredicably.

If you want to you can have numerous named yields in your layout if you want to let the templates being rendered inject content into the layout ("outside the box").

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Neigbornow</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= yield :meta %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= yield :js %>
    <%= yield :css %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% if @user.nil? %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <% elsif user_signed_in? && current_page?(user_step_path) || %>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/header_address" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'layouts/header_rest' %>
    <% end %>
      <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <!- I would really recommend that you wrap this in an element -!>
    <div id="main">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can then use `content_for` to provide content for named yields from the view:

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<% content_for :meta do %>
  <meta property="og:title" content="<%= @article.title %>" />
<% end %>
```

See:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time, this totally makes sence to me, but, if I do it, as described above, then my autocomplete desappears

Comment: It keeps showing this error : Error: Algolia Places: 'container' must point to an <input> element. I researched for this one, but the solution is, to changed a QuerySlector, which unfortunatelly doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please have a look above, under P.S. - edited version, cais this also a bad way to do it? Like this it works

Comment: No, still completely wrong. Your main `yield` should be in the `<body>` tag of the document. No where else. Just because it happens to silence whatever immediate error you have does not mean its a good idea. Try using the HTML5 validator on the resulting markup and you'll see that its a really bad idea.

Comment: Why don't you ask instead how you should actually be integrating the autocomplete and provide the relevant information instead?

Comment: I asked about autocomlete here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947989/algolia-places-and-rails-autocomplete-form), but since noone answered, this was the only solution, I came up with. I am obviously not a pro and sometimes I really feel comepletely lost. The level of knowledge I have right now won't let me debug correctly every time I have a problem.

Comment: I think the issue is actually tied to the fact that algolia is not really built to work with tubolinks. When you call places in that example you are binding an event handler directly to the element itself (`document.querySelector('#address')`). So it will only work on the initial page load. The reason your strange workaround works is that your page is so completely malformed so that turbolinks is actually replacing all the script tags when it refreshes the page.  What you can do is disable turbolinks or create a handler that runs every time turbolinks refreshes the page.

Comment: You can do that by wrapping your code in `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e){ ... })`. Which fires every time turbolinks replaces the page. See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Comment: Now, all of a sudden, it worked, without me changing anything. It's a mystery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you have two `yield` statements. I suppose you don't need the one inside `<meta>` tags?

The `yield` inside the `meta` tag is loading the form before the javascript is included. That could be the reason why the first form has no autocomplete.

Comment: True! But deleting the one in meta destroyed my autocomplete. So I deleted the one in the body and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: That sounds more like it will break everything else in your application.

Comment: Having the `yield` for the form in the `meta` tag doesn't seems right. You might want rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

just put your javascript and stylesheet tag helper before the csrf_meta_tags and csp_meta_tag:

```
<head>
<title>Neigbornow</title>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'autocomplete' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>

</head>
```